# To use %in% to a subset in R

Tags: r, subset

I have data 'data' in R that contains 2 columns 
data$user_id = 323, 10, 2033, 112,... and data$value= 231, 4321, 90,.. Futhermore `dim(data)= 41000 2`

I have a vector `u <- c(25,36,38,..)` and `length(u)=900`

I now want to make a subset of 'data' so that 'user_id' is equal the vector 'u'. In other words, I want all user_id's in u and their entry in data.
In R I do this

```
newdata <- subset(data, data$user_id %in% u)
```

To make sure that they have the same type I can do this

```
newdata <- subset(data, as.numeric(data$user_id) %in% as.numeric(u))
```

When I type `head(newdata)` I can see it make sense and `dim(newdata) = 900 2` which is also what I want.

But when I type `newdata` I get printet data which is very strange. How can that be?

Comment: Can you describe the `strange` part.  BTW you don't need `data$` inside `subset`

Comment: When I type newdata I should get all 900 values but I get 41000 values namely data.

Comment: Can you update with the `str` of the `data`?  Also, do you find this strangeness by using a subset of your dataset?  Is it possible that you have duplicates for the 'user_id'

Comment: you can try: `newdata <- data[data$user_id %in% u, ]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean if I can update the 'str' of the data? I have also tried Rime's suggestion and I et the same thing as before.

Comment: The result you got is unusual.  One possible way you get the whole dataset is when there are duplicates for the `user_id`.  It is not mentioned in your post and without a small reproducible example, we can only do guesswork.  Can you check the `length(unique(data$user_id))`

Comment: some reproducible data would be nice: `dput(head(data, 50))` for data and `dput(head(u, 50))`

Comment: The problem is solved if I type as.numeric( subset(data, as.numeric(data$user_id) %in% as.numeric(u))).

Answer (score 0):

`subset` uses non-standard evaluation.

```
newdata <- subset(data, user_id %in% u)
```